# Magento - Add a Product to the Cart via Querystring

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, magento, cart

I'm aware that a product can be added via querystring in Magento.

Pattern:

```
/path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
```

And if I have a required custom options:

```
/path/to/magento/checkout/cart/add?product=$id&qty=$qty&options[$id]=$value
```

If custom option is for example "field" or "drop_down", it's simple;

My querstion is: How to add a product via querystring if one of custom option is a **file** type?

I would like to add a file, as custom option value, that is already uploaded on server with AJAX (before product is added to cart).

Can it be done? And how?

Thank you for any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files must be uploaded with POST requests, not GET (query string). You cannot use the built in add to cart url in that way without modifying the controller, which is not a good idea. Instead maybe make your own add to cart controller and copy the code from the core action and adjust it to accept filenames in the query string.

However, I have a feeling you are just trying to add products to cart without loading a new page. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm just trying to add ajax image upload. That's all. I suppose a dirty work is ahead. I didn't found any shortcut/solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom option should be a filename (or some other unique reference to the file), not the file itself. Any  code that needs to operate on the file can then use the filename to get to the actual file since it is already on your server.

Comment: -1 for solution. I though of that, but it must be a file. If it is a file, then I get automatically download link in cart, checkout, backend etc. What I also need. Your solution makes just more work and customization.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but if you have a reference to the file as well as the actual file on your server, then you *can* do all of those things (download, link, etc in checkout, cart and backend).